# Jquery/ajax getting undefined for variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The issue I'm running into but can't quite seem to figure out is related to the "game" variable that I have inserted into the queryURL, it is coming back as undefined and I am not quite sure why. I believe it should be coming back as whatever the game text is for that button, but it appears I am incorrect. I have compared my code to other similar code and it looks roughly the same, and directly the same when it comes to that portion of the code.

```js
    var games = ["Zelda", "Super Mario", "Sonic the Hedgehog"];
    var gameGif;

    function displayGameGif() {
   
       $("#gif-buttons").on("click", function(){
        var game = $(this).attr("data-game");
        var queryURL = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + game + "&api_key=rI1IycXL1PKjHBOLNDpExvjGMTfQABIr&limit=10";
   
        $.ajax({
            url: queryURL,
            mathod: "GET"
        }).then(function(response) {
           console.log(queryURL);

           var results = response.data;
           for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
               var gameDiv = $("<div>");
               var p = $("<p>").text("Rating: " + results[i].rating);
               var gameImage = $("<img>")

               gameImage.attr("src", results[i].images.fixed_height.url);
           
               gameDiv.append(p);
               gameDiv.append(gameImage);
               $("#game-gifs").prepend(gameDiv);
           }
   

        });
   
        });
   
    };
   
    function renderButtons() {
        $("#gif-buttons").empty();
   
        for(var i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
            var a = $("<button>");
               a.addClass("gif-btn");
               a.attr("data-game", games[i]);
               a.text(games[i]);
               $("#gif-buttons").append(a);
        }
    }
   
    $("#add-game").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var game = $("#game-input").val().trim();
        games.push(game);
        renderButtons();
   
    });
   
    $(document).on("click", ".gif-btn", displayGameGif);
   
   renderButtons();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <title>Video Game Gifs</title>
</head>


<body>
   <div class="container">
       <h1>Gif Search</h1>
  <!--buttons should go here-->
   <div id="gif-buttons"></div>   
   <!--gifs should go here-->
   <div id="game-gifs"></div>

   <form id="giphy-form">

       <label for="game-input">Add a Game</label>
       <input type="text" id="game-input"> 
       <br>
       <input id="add-game" type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>

 </div>   
 <script src="assets/giphy.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *it is coming back as undefined* When? Under what circumstance? Are you getting an error or just `undefined` as a value somewhere. Give us some insight.

Comment: I apologize, it is coming back as undefined whenever I try to use the button itself. There is no error, basically "game" should fill in whatever game that button is labeled. However when I click the button and view the console log, on the part of the queryURL where the the of the game should be, it just says undefined.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but console.logging out $(this).attr("data-game"); also seems to come back as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your buttons don't get wired up to any real `click` event handler until `displayGameGif` executes and that doesn't execute until you click a button. So, you need to click the first button just to hook up the buttons to the real event handler and the second click works.

Moving the event binding a bit solves the issue.

```js
var games = ["Zelda", "Super Mario", "Sonic the Hedgehog"];
    var gameGif;


   
       $("#gif-buttons").on("click", function(){
        var game = $(this).attr("data-game");
        var queryURL = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + game + "&api_key=rI1IycXL1PKjHBOLNDpExvjGMTfQABIr&limit=10";
   
        $.ajax({
            url: queryURL,
            mathod: "GET"
        }).then(function(response) {
           console.log(queryURL);

           var results = response.data;
           for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
               var gameDiv = $("<div>");
               var p = $("<p>").text("Rating: " + results[i].rating);
               var gameImage = $("<img>")

               gameImage.attr("src", results[i].images.fixed_height.url);
           
               gameDiv.append(p);
               gameDiv.append(gameImage);
               $("#game-gifs").prepend(gameDiv);
           }
   

        });
   
        });
   
 
   
    function renderButtons() {
        $("#gif-buttons").empty();
   
        for(var i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
            var a = $("<button>");
               a.addClass("gif-btn");
               a.attr("data-game", games[i]);
               a.text(games[i]);
               $("#gif-buttons").append(a);
        }
    }
   
    $("#add-game").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var game = $("#game-input").val().trim();
        games.push(game);
        renderButtons();
   
    });
   

   
   renderButtons();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <title>Video Game Gifs</title>
</head>


<body>
   <div class="container">
       <h1>Gif Search</h1>
  <!--buttons should go here-->
   <div id="gif-buttons"></div>   
   <!--gifs should go here-->
   <div id="game-gifs"></div>

   <form id="giphy-form">

       <label for="game-input">Add a Game</label>
       <input type="text" id="game-input"> 
       <br>
       <input id="add-game" type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>

 </div>   
 <script src="assets/giphy.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, that did fix one of the odd issues I was having so thank you for that, but not the actual problem of         var queryURL = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + game + "&api_key=rI1IycXL1PKjHBOLNDpExvjGMTfQABIr&limit=10";                                     the portion where it says + game + coming back as undefined in the console log when running this in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem, I was assigning the initial function to a div  "$("#gif-buttons").on("click", function(){" so when trying to call on the function later on the buttons it was trying to target the Div and not the button.